# Keep files one daily, one 3 days and one week and delete others

Tags: bash, powershell

I have a folder containing database backup files for the last 15 days.
I need to delete all files and keep only one daily, one 3 days and one week.
Can someone help on this ?

I tried some scripts but none met my requirements

```
mkdir -p monthly
mkdir -p weekly

ln backup_$NOW.tgz weekly/

# find current month
month=$(date +%Y-%m-)
# find the first file of the current month in the weekly folder
first_monthly=$(ls --sort=time -1 weekly/*$month* 2>/dev/null | tail -1)
# and put it in the monthly folder
ln -f $first_monthly monthly/

# we need only 5 weekly backups
ls --sort=time -1 weekly/* 2>/dev/null | tail -n+6 >> /tmp/deletebackups.txt
# we need only 5 monthly backups
ls --sort=time -1 monthly/* 2>/dev/null | tail -n+6 >> /tmp/deletebackups.txt

# delete the extra files
#rm $(cat /tmp/deletebackups.txt) 2>/dev/null
xargs --arg-file /tmp/deletebackups.txt rm
```

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to determine what to keep or delete. it uses an array of "age in days to keep" and then checks to see if the file age is in that collection.

```
$DaysOldToKeep = @(
    0
    3
    7
    )

$SourceDir = $env:TEMP
$Today = (Get-Date).Date

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -File |
    Sort-Object -Property CreationTime

foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)
    {
    $DaysOld = ($Today - $FL_Item.CreationTime).Days

    if ($DaysOld -notin $DaysOldToKeep)
        {
        Write-Warning ('[ {0} ] is [ {1} ] days old & should be removed.' -f $FL_Item.Name, $DaysOld)
        }
        else
        {
        Write-Host ('    [ {0} ] is [ {1} ] days old & should be KEPT.' -f $FL_Item.Name, $DaysOld)
        }
    }
```

truncated output ...

```
WARNING: [ testing-making-dir-and-file.txt ] is [ 9 ] days old & should be removed.
WARNING: [ hd4B753.tmp ] is [ 8 ] days old & should be removed.
    [ Itunes_AlbumAutoRating_Disable.ps1_2019-04-08.log ] is [ 7 ] days old & should be KEPT.
    [ vscode-inno-updater-1554768842.log ] is [ 7 ] days old & should be KEPT.
    [ hd464FA.tmp ] is [ 7 ] days old & should be KEPT.
    [ hd4E2F0.tmp ] is [ 7 ] days old & should be KEPT.
WARNING: [ Genre-List_2019-04-09.log ] is [ 6 ] days old & should be removed.
WARNING: [ Grouping-Strings-List_2019-04-10.log ] is [ 5 ] days old & should be removed.
WARNING: [ Itunes_R-PC-SC_Save.ps1_2019-04-11.log ] is [ 4 ] days old & should be removed.
    [ Magenoob_-_Merged_User_Info.csv ] is [ 3 ] days old & should be KEPT.
    [ Itunes_Default-Rating_Set.ps1_2019-04-12.log ] is [ 3 ] days old & should be KEPT.
    [ MagicTheGathering_-_Scryfall-Default-Cards.json ] is [ 3 ] days old & should be KEPT.
WARNING: [ hd4C490.tmp ] is [ 2 ] days old & should be removed.
WARNING: [ hd45A92.tmp ] is [ 1 ] days old & should be removed.
    [ exthost-825471.cpuprofile ] is [ 0 ] days old & should be KEPT.
    [ vscode-inno-updater-1555314279.log ] is [ 0 ] days old & should be KEPT.
    [ npp.7.6.6.Installer.x64.exe ] is [ 0 ] days old & should be KEPT.
    [ hd43E2A.tmp ] is [ 0 ] days old & should be KEPT.
    [ hd44D37.tmp ] is [ 0 ] days old & should be KEPT.
    [ hd4488C.tmp ] is [ 0 ] days old & should be KEPT.
    [ hd45A09.tmp ] is [ 0 ] days old & should be KEPT.
    [ Itunes_AlbumAutoRating_Disable.ps1_2019-04-15.log ] is [ 0 ] days old & should be KEPT.
```

Comment: thank you, yes this good i can see the files should removed but the script only give me result but not apply remove, who can apply delete for this files ?

Comment: @user3786217 - um, er, use the `Remove-Item` cmdlet where the delete message is seems like a workable idea ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey If you delete files not matching 0,3,7 days age, what do you do tomorrow?

Comment: will delete other files not mach 0,3,7 based on creation date

Comment: @LotPings - that is what the OP requested, yes? [*grin*] _to delete_ the unwanted files. i agree that the logic is a tad off ... as you point out, how can there be any 3- or 7-days-old files if you always delete the 2-day-old files?

Comment: @user3786217 - apparently i am not understanding your intent ... i thot you wanted to delete the files that were NOT "today, 3 days old, or 7 days old". [*blush*]  what _do_ you want?

Answer (score 0):

A way to retrieve the first newest files would be :

```sh
ls -t weekly/ | head -1
```

And to have the rest of the oldest, to delete :

```sh
ls -t weekly/ | tail +2
```

If you want to keep it bash only, it may be the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this (remove -whatif if you want really remove):

```
$File1Founded=$false
$File3Founded=$false
$File7Founded=$false
$CurrentDate1=(get-date).Date
$CurrentDate3=(get-date).AddDays(-3).Date
$CurrentDate7=(get-date).AddDays(-7).Date

Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\test1" -file | sort CreationTime -Descending | %{

$DateFile=$_.CreationTime.Date

if ($DateFile -eq $CurrentDate1)
{
   if ($File1Founded)
   {
      $_
   }
   else
   {
       $File1Founded=$true
   }

}
elseif ($DateFile -eq $CurrentDate3)
{
   if ($File3Founded)
   {
      $_
   }
   else
   {
       $File3Founded=$true
   }
}
elseif ($DateFile -eq $CurrentDate7)
{
   if ($File7Founded)
   {
      $_
   }
   else
   {
       $File7Founded=$true
   }
}
else
{
    $_
}

} | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```